# Reactjs authentication Firebase check without localstorage

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to create a login with React + Firebase WITHOUT using localstorage because of security reasons.

Since I can edit localstorage and change "key" value and then the user will get in without valid credential I am trying to create one of below situations:

1- Save user data, like token, to once reload ( or refresh )  the page the user stay connected.

OR

2- Use a function from Firebase to check if token is valid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dude firebase works on tokens. XD